# How do I produce a report to show the number of occurrences an employee has been absent from work

Tags: t-sql

I have been asked to generate a report to show the number of occurrences an employee is absent from work sick.

If an employee is absent from work for 3 consecutive days this will be counted as 1 occurrence. If they then return to work and are then absent again for another 2 consecutive days this will be recorded as 2 occurrences.

I need to generate a report to show the number of occurrences an employee is away from work sick within a 6 month period.

I have set out an example below of the data showing an employee's absence records and how i need the report to look.

How data shows in database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7kYU.png)

Name         Absence Dates
John Smith   01-Sep-19
John Smith   02-Sep-19
John Smith   03-Sep-19
John Smith   10-Sep-19
John Smith   11-Sep-19

How i wish for the report to look:
Name         Occurrences 
John Smith   2

I would be grateful for any assistance with writing to code to achieve this result.

Comment: Hi Laura - this looks suspiciously like homework ;) Please include examples of what you've tried and what you're stuck on.

Comment: Just a note on you data model, if you have no retiurn date, then it's impossible to determine how long the person was away from work for. Also if you have more than one John Smith in your system how to you determine who s who? you should be using a unique ID for each employee in your data model that is unique to the employee.

Comment: Hi Markoorm- thanks for your response. I can guarantee you this is not homework, it is a report which has been requested by my employer to track employees absences.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, as you should really do some of this yourself, however, based on what you have detailed in your quesiton, you could use the approach below to count up any spells of absence, within a 6 month period.

Assumes you would be compiling this using SQL Server

```
declare @absences table (empid nvarchar(10), [abs date] date, [ret date] date);
declare @staff table ([empid] int, [name1] nvarchar(50), [name2] nvarchar(50), [surname] nvarchar(50));

-- put some test values in the staff table to work with
insert into @staff
values 
(1, 'John', 'Lewis', 'Smith'), -- using a unique ID here, in any good system this should be an incremental number for each new staff member added to the table
(2, 'James', 'Thomas', 'Brown') 

-- put some test values in the absences table to work with
insert into @absences
values 
(1, '2019-07-01', '2019-07-04'), -- userid, absence date & return date
(1, '2019-08-04', '2019-08-06'),
(2, '2019-07-02', '2019-07-05'),
(2, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-07')

select count(*) spellsoff, empid, name1, name2, surname, [days absent]
from
(
  select 
  s.empid,
  s.name1,
  s.name2,
  s.surname,
  a.[abs date],
  a.[ret date],
  datediff(d,a.[abs date], a.[ret date]) [days absent]
from @staff s
  left join @absences a
  on s.empid = a.empid
where [abs date] >= DATEADD(M,-6,GETDATE()) -- pull back those employeess that have been absent in the last 6 months from today's date
)doff
group by empid, name1, name2, surname, [days absent]
```

Gives you the following breakdown:

```
spellsoff   empid   name1   name2   surname days absent
   1          1     John    Lewis   Smith       2
   1          1     John    Lewis   Smith       3
   1          2     James   Thomas  Brown       2
   1          2     James   Thomas  Brown       3
```